# Is it necessary to put aside some emergency memory when new fails?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linux-mint

Suppose I have a function that uses "new", do I need to set aside some emergency memory in case "new" fails? Such as:

```
static char* emerg_mem = new char[EMERG_MEM_SZ];

FooElement* Foo::createElement()
{
    try
    {
        FooElement* ptr;
        ptr = new FooElement();
        return ptr;
    }
    catch(bad_alloc ex)
    {
        delete[] emerg_mem;
        emerg_mem = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

So that there is enough (EMERG_MEM_SZ) memory remaining for class destructor functions etc, and to gracefully exit the program?

I am using GCC on Linux Mint, but I suppose this question could apply to any platform.

Comment: How would this extra memory help?  It is already allocated so it is not like something else can use it.

Comment: I think that if the `std::bad_alloc` is thrown you are in a lot more trouble than what you can possibly remedy with the "emergency memory". Either you tried to allocate bigger chunk than is available, then arguably you could continue the program execution if you can do without it. Or you got the exception trying to allocate something relatively small in which case your machine ran out of memory and your program is pretty much unable to do anything at all.

Comment: And frankly, if allocation fails your process is probably doomed anyway. It's very hard to recover from something like that.

Comment: Assuming this was necessary and you tried this approach. What happens if you later fail to allocate again? Is anything responsible for re-reserving that memory? If not, it would only be a practical solution when you are certain the error won't be fully recovered from (you'll terminate very soon) to allow clean-up related activities like logging. As far as I understand it, that's one of the few use cases for [`std::set_new_handler`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/set_new_handler).

Answer (score 5):

> So that there is enough (EMERG_MEM_SZ) memory remaining for class destructor functions etc, and to gracefully exit the program?

Before attempting to provide such memory for destructors, you should first be able to argue some reason why your destructors would need to allocate dynamic memory in the first place. Such requirement is a serious red flag about the design of the class.

> Is it necessary to put aside some emergency memory when new fails?

Not necessarily. Firstly, graceful exit is often possible without allocating any dynamic memory. Secondly, a program running within the protection of an operating system doesn't necessarily need to terminate gracefully in such a dire situation as lack of memory.

---

P.S. Some systems (Linux in particular, given certain configuration) "overcommit" memory and never throw `std::bad_alloc`. Instead, allocation always succeeds, physical memory isn't allocated until it is actually accessed, and if no memory is available at that time the process (or some other process) is killed to free some memory. On such system there is no way in C++ to recover from lack of memory.

Comment: I feel lack of memory is an overestimated problem. Many platforms with tight restrictions may encounter them in the course of normal operations or upon unreasonable user requests. Even for platforms that don't usually see failed allocations, it's no cause for abandoning ship.

Comment: The only reason I've seen of having a memory pool to allocate from, is for creating a message window to inform the user about imminent exit.

Comment: @Ripi2. You don't need to reserve for that. Catch near the base of the call stack (after all memory is released because of stack unwinding) then you will have plenty of memory for a message window (in nearly all normal acting applications, even if there was a leak that took all memory there is usually enough normal objects released that there will now be free memory available for a message box).

Answer (score 2):

I would say no.

When your application is out of memory and throws an exception the stack will start to unwind (thus destroying and releasing memory as it goes). As a general rule destructors should not be using dynamic memory allocation more like they should be releasing the memory.

Thus if you have correctly used RAII then you will gain memory back as the stack unwinds, which potentially allows you to catch and continue (if the thing throwing is a discrete task whose results can be discarded).

Also in most situations your application will slow to an unusable crawl long before actual throwing an out of memory exception (as the OS tries to consolidate memory to get you that elusive slot).